# Explode a SparseVector column into rows containing index and value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have SparseVectors generated from IDF transformation that look like:

```
user='1234', idf=SparseVector(174, {0: 0.4709, 5: 0.8967, 7: 0.9625, 8: 0.9814,...})
```

I would like to explode this into something like:

```
|index|rating|user|
|0    |0.4709|1234|
|5    |0.8967|1234|
|7    |0.9625|1234|
|8    |0.9814|1234|
.
.
.
```

My objective is to take these `index,value` tuples and perform an ALS step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This task will require an `UserDefinedFunction`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1234', SparseVector(174, {0: 0.4709, 5: 0.8967, 7: 0.9625, 8: 0.9814}))
]).toDF("user", "idf")

@udf("map<long, double>")
def vector_as_map(v):
   if isinstance(v, SparseVector):
       return dict(zip(v.indices.tolist(), v.values.tolist()))
   elif isinstance(v, DenseVector):
      return dict(zip(range(len(v)), v.values.tolist()))

df.select("user", explode(vector_as_map("idf")).alias("index", "rating")).show()
```

which would give you and expected result:

```
+----+-----+------+                                                             
|user|index|rating|
+----+-----+------+
|1234|    0|0.4709|
|1234|    8|0.9814|
|1234|    5|0.8967|
|1234|    7|0.9625|
+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: Yes, so what seems to be working for me is this: ```@udf(returnType=MapType(LongType(), DoubleType()))``` Any thoughts why that would work but the string doesn't?

Comment: Not a clue. I've tested this with both 2.3 and 2.4 and couldn't reproduce the problem. Furthermore [SPARK-19427](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19427) has been resolved in 2.2, so it should work with all versions, where decorator with type works. Sounds a bit like there is no `SparkContext` in the scope.

Comment: very handy, thanks